# Unable to display events via click in resourceTimelineWeek view of FullCalendar 5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Unable to display the events getting created via a prompt and getting the "title" of the event to be created by clicking on the table cells. After debugging I was able to find that the event was created but somehow it is not getting rendered.
The way I'm creating events is just by clicking on the table cells and then a prompt pops up and you write the title of the event and technically it should display the event on that selected table cell.

Hopefully, the following screenshot will help.
Feel free to ask any questions.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import FullCalendar, { formatDate } from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import BasicApp from './Demo';
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from './event-utils';
import {resourceDayGridPlugin} from 'fullcalendar-scheduler';


function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
    console.log(eventInfo)
    return (
      <>
        <b>{eventInfo.timeText}</b>
        <i>{eventInfo.event.title}</i>
        {/* <p>Hi There</p> */}
      </>
    )
  }


const DemoApp = () => {

    const [state1, setState1] = useState(false);
    const [state2, setState2] = useState(false);

    const [weekendsVisible, setWeekendsVisible] = useState(false);
    const [currentEvents, setCurrentEvents] = useState([])
    
    const handleState1 = () => {
        setState1(true);
        setState2(false);
    }
    const handleState2 = () => {
        setState2(true);
        setState1(false);
    }

    const handleDateSelect = (selectInfo) => {
        let title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event')
        let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar
        console.log(title)

        calendarApi.unselect() // clear date selection

        if (title) {
           return calendarApi.addEvent({
            id: createEventId(),
            title,
            start: selectInfo.startStr,
            end: selectInfo.endStr,
            allDay: selectInfo.allDay
            })
        }
    }

    const handleEventClick = (clickInfo) => {
    if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`)) {
        clickInfo.event.remove()
    }
    alert('Event: ' + clickInfo.event.title);

    // change the border color just for fun
    clickInfo.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }

    const handleEvents = (events) => {
    setCurrentEvents(events);
    }

    const handleWeekendsToggle = () => {
    setWeekendsVisible(!weekendsVisible);
    }

    let resourceTimeline_Z =  {
    type: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
    duration: { days: 2 }
    }

    return (
        <>
          <div className="inline">
                <button className={`Demo__app ${state1 ? 'selected' : ''}`} onClick={handleState1}>
                   Grid Timeline
                </button>
                <button className={`Demo__app ${state2 ? 'selected' : ''}`} onClick={handleState2}>
                    Resource Timeline
                </button>
                <div className='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
                <label>
                    <input
                    type='checkbox'
                    checked={weekendsVisible}
                    onChange={handleWeekendsToggle}
                    ></input>
                    toggle weekends
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            {
                state1 ? 
                    <BasicApp /> 
                      :
                    state2 ?   
                        <div className='demo-app-main'>
                        <FullCalendar
                            plugins={[   resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin  ]}
                            headerToolbar={{
                                left: 'prev,next today',
                                center: 'title',
                                right: 'resourceTimelineWeek'
                            }}
                            initialView="resourceTimelineWeek"
                            datesAboveResources={true}
                            // views= {
                            //     resourceTimelineDays = {
                            //         type: "resourceTimelineWeek",
                            //         duration: { days: 4 }
                            //     }
                            //   }
                            eventDisplay={true}
                            display='block'
                            resources= {[
                                {
                                    id: 'A',
                                    groupId: '1',
                                    title: 'Resource A'
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'B',
                                    groupdId: '1',
                                    title: 'Resource B'
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'C',
                                    groupId: '2',
                                    title: 'Resource C'
                                }
                            ]}
                            editable={true}
                            selectable={true}
                            selectMirror={true}
                            slotMinTime="08:00:00"
                            slotMaxTime="19:00:00"
                            // dayMaxEvents={true}
                            dayMaxEvents={false}
                            weekends={weekendsVisible}
                            initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS} // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
                            select={handleDateSelect}
                            eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
                            eventClick={handleEventClick}
                            eventsSet={handleEvents}  
                            
                        />
                        </div> 
                        : 
                        <BasicApp />
            }
            
        </>  
        )
  
}
export default DemoApp;
```

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Anyway, since you didn't specify a resource ID for your created events, they cannot show up in the Timeline View. Think about it logically, if the event does not have a resource ID then how is fullCalendar supposed to know which resource to display it against? As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback the selectInfo will contain the data about the selected resource, if the selection was made on a resource-aware view such as Timeline. (If the selection was made using a different, non-resource view, then you will need to ask the user which resource to associate the event with).

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but that extra comment doesn't address any of these comments or enable anyone to solve your problem any more than I have already suggested

Comment: Hey, so I have given you the code in which I am having a problem, as you can see in the resources prop I have given the "ID" to each "Resource", is it the same thing you were saying in your 2nd comment.

Comment: Yes the resources have an ID, but the **events** don't. That's what my comment is taking about - read it again more carefully please. When you do `calendarApi.addEvent`, you don't provide the new event with a resource ID. Therefore fullCalendar does not know where to put the event in the timeline, because it does not belong to any resource

Comment: Yep, it worked, thanks a lot @ADyson I added this "resourceId" prop in the calendarApi.addEvent function and it worked. You were right the addEvent was not been able to figure out the resourceId. Thanks for the help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify a resource ID for your created events, they cannot show up in the Timeline View. If the event does not have a resource ID then fullCalendar does not know which resource to display it against, so it simply does not display it at all.

Specifically the problem is when you do `calendarApi.addEvent`, you don't provide the new event with a resource ID. You need to provide a resourceID in the object you are passing to `addEvent`.